# Are .h files treated differently by the compiler or "just" a naming convention?

Tags: c++, c, header-files

I'm new to C family programming and compiling. I'm trying to understand what .c/.cpp files vs .h files are on a low technical level. I understand .h files are used to specify an interface and .c or .cpp files for implementation. However I'm wondering if this difference is reflected in how the compiler works or if it is "just" a naming convention to simplify for us humans? Could you in theory have the implemntation in a .h file and still have it compile? Or specify an interface in a .c file? I'm asking to better understand what the compiler actually does.

Comment: Short answer - just a convention. If you want to dive deeper - try to rename a .c file as .h and compile. If you're using something other than simple command line for compilation (make file/IDE), you may find it interesting..

Answer (score 10):

Technically, there is no difference between any extension as far as the compiler is concerned. It's same as if you had typed manually the contents of any file in place where you put the `#include`. You can type `#include "foo.pdf"` and the compiler will include a file foo.pdf successfully, as long as that file contains code (despite the extension)

By convention now, one usually puts declarations in .h/hpp files (or template definitions) and the implementation in .c/cpp files.

Many libraries have a single-file implementation, with the aid of inline variables/functions as well.

Sometimes also the include file does not even exist, for example when including a standard STL file (like `string`), the compiler might not read the file at all, but cache it/implement it however it wants.

More info on `#include` in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-include-directive-c-cpp?view=vs-2019) and [CPPReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include).

Comment: A funny one: `#include "/dev/tty"`. Only for unix-like though; I wonder what would be the equivalent (if any) in Windows :-)

Comment: It would be the same nonsense as #include <con>. Back in Windows 98 this would even crash your pc.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler does what you tell it to do. It will compile files which you specify as its inputs, and as part of this compilation, it will include other files in these input files if you tell it to do so using `#include` preprocessor directives.

If you tell the compiler to compile a `.h` file (and pass in command-line options to make it treat it as a source file, such as `-x c` for gcc), it will compile it just fine. If you `#include "a.cpp"`, it will get included normally.

Comment: Specifying a file name is part of “what you tell it to do.” As this answer alludes to, file names on the command line are treated differently according to their extensions—`-x c` is needed when a `.h` file is given on the command line since the compiler will not treat it as a C source file **due to the extension**. So, yes, `.h` files are treated differently than `.c` files by GCC.

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly just a naming convention to help us organize our code; there's no low-level technical difference, at least for user-defined headers (some implementations may have "pre-compiled" headers such that there's no readable source text).  It all has to be valid C or C++ code.  The C language standard names all the standard library headers with a `.h` extension, so that's the convention most people follow for headers. The C++ language standard names all the standard library headers with *no* extension (`iostream`, `string`, etc.), but most people follow the `.h` (or `.hpp`) naming convention, mainly to make searches easier.

Individual tools may care - gcc will treat a `.c` file differently from a `.cpp` file, an IDE may display `.h` files differently from `.c` files - but that's a function of that particular tool, not the language.

Some (admittedly ancient) systems used a file naming convention that didn't allow for `.h` or `.c` extensions *at all* - MPE on HP3000 used the convention `filename.groupname.accountname`.  The C compiler on MPE was able to map standard header names like `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` correctly, but user-defined headers *had* to follow the `filename.groupname.accountname` format (all of which which had to fit into 35 characters or less, including the delimiters, leading to wonderfully readable names like `MYCODEHDR.DEVELOP.BODE`).

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed just a transparent convention to the compiler, that is useful in making the big projects more organized as the interface/implementation duality.

The separation is practical especially in reducing coupling in C++ designs, which allows for an easy (interface/implementation) customization in the future.

The separation is also useful for abstraction, a.k.a, hiding implementation details from the users in case of libraries, which makes it handier for users who have access only to the interface, and they are not supposed to bother themselves with implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a convention, in case of header files.

You can include also some other code, a old pattern were:

file.inc:

```
  MACRO("-a", "--append", "this will append text"),
  MACRO("-b", "--bottom", "something for bottom"),
```

and in main file:

```
char *options[] = {
#define MACRO(short, long, help) (short)
#include "file.inc"
#undef MACRO
NULL
};

char *help[] = {
#define MACRO(short, long, help) (help)
#include "file.inc"
#undef MACRO
NULL
};
```

and such constructs.
Now it is not so frequent. I think in the book *20 century C* there are still some of such tricks, but personally, I would prefer an external pre-preprocessor.

Linux kernel includes sometimes other *.c files, e.g. modifying few functions with macro.  I do not think it is usually a good coding style, but kernel uses it to build e.g. to drivers in parallel, which share 99.9% of the code.

Note: the `#include <include.h>` is different. In this case, the `include.h` could be interpreted as a label for the compiler (which could use it as a flag). There is no need to have standard library headers in the system, but modern common compilers have headers also for standard libraries.

An h file could be empty or it should contain a final line feed `\n`. No other requirements. For context, it should be valid C.

Historically, there was a pre-processor `cpp`, and the compiler `cc`, as two different programs. So the preprocessor does know nothing about the filename convention and structure. Compiler than compile the rest, just as a single file. [See above about possible exception for standard libraries].  Note: I saw also use of C pre-processor in shell scripts, on none C files. (gcc -E

Last point. Some compilers, e.g. gcc, use the file extension to select which language to use. You can overwrite it with command line options. But so, `gcc a.h` could not compile the file in the way you expect. E.g. on my system `touch a.h b.c; gcc a.h; gcc b.c` gives two different results.